# How to add spring component from one .war to another

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

My situation: I have one war module, lets name it source.war and second war module destination.war

In source.war I have a spring component adnotated by @Component, and I want to use it in destination.war module. As I know it is not possible to add one war to another. I also know that I can pack this component to .jar file.

And here is my question - how to do that, or how make it possible to use component from source.war in destination.war? I'm begginer in Spring, please give me detailed advices. I'm using maven to managing my project.

Comment: You need to add this component to both of the wars.

Comment: Spring does not provide functionality to manage dependencies. Hence, my suggestion is to create a separate java project and add these common components. Then, in your source and destination add this java project as a maven dependency.